# IMAP Fetch causing slow loading times

Tags: php, imap

I have a PHP webpage that displays a list of email subject lines and the body from the past month. There are only about 25 emails for it to load and they are reasonably short with no attachment. To achieve this I am using the below code:

```
$result = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
    foreach ($result as $overview) {

        $timestamp=$overview->udate;

        if (date('m', $timestamp) === date('m')) {
            $timestamp = $overview->udate;
            $realdate = gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);

            $messageBody = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$overview->uid,1);

            echo "<tr><td><button style='background: none; border: none; padding: 0;' onclick=\"showContent('".$overview->uid."')\" class=\"\">" . " {$overview->subject} " . "</button></td><td>" . "{$realdate} " . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td id='".$overview->uid."' class='w3-container w3-hide '><div><p>$messageBody</p></div></td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

This does eventually load but it is taking about 30 seconds, my question is is there anyway for me to reduce these loading times?

Comment: If you store the current time at the start of the script you quoted and then subtract it from the current time, how much time did pass? If half a minute, then the script is slow indeed. If not, then you have your primary problem with something else.

Comment: Why are you fetching 25 separate bodies to not even display them?  That is what is taking a long time: 25 separate round trips (or however many there are)

Comment: @Max I have a setup on another page to change that from hidden to show when the subject line is clicked.

Comment: Maybe you should do that on demand, rather than all ahead, or do it in the background.  Also the body isn't always Part 1.

Comment: As an update, even just running the foreach loop on it's own without anything in it, causes the page to take over 6 seconds to load. I think i'm going to have to look at getting the emails saved to a database instead of reading them from the IMAP server directly